# Use MCT on $(2x-4)^{-1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Use Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove that

$$f(x) = [(2x-4)^{-1/2}]1_{(2,4]} + 01_{\{2\}}$$

is Lebesgue integrable on $[2,4]$.

According to notes from a different class

[image]

So I just replace $x$ w/ $f(x)$?

It seems then that I just say that MCT gives us:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[2,4]} g_n(x) dx = \int_{[2,4]} f(x) dx = \int_{[2,4]} |f(x)| dx$$

I just evaluate

$$\int_{[2,4]} g_n(x) dx$$

then take the limit. If it's $< \infty$, QED?

Answer (score 1):

Changing variables you can work with the integral:

$$\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx=\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} \, dx$$

Consider the sequence of simple functions $\phi_n \leqslant f$ where

$$\phi_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(k/2^n)^{-1/2}1_{[(k-1)/2^n, k/2^n]}(x).$$

Since the sequence converges monotonically to $f$ it follows by the MCT that,

$$\int_{[0,1]}f=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int\phi_n= \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}(k/2^n)^{-1/2}m([(k-1)/2^n,k/2^n])\\= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}\frac1{\sqrt{k}}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{\sqrt{k}} =2.$$

Comment: Thanks RRL. I'm guessing that implies Lebesgue integrability because $f \ge 0$. How did you come up w/ that sequence?

Comment: @BCLC:  I used a sequence of step functions on dyadic intervals, motivated by the fact that the integral of each step function corrresponds to a lower Riemann sum.  In this way, I produced a monotone sequence of simple functions that converges to the integrand and applied MCT to find the integral as the limit of the sequence of integrals.

Comment: By lower you mean, right Riemann sum? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Definition

Comment: Btw RRL, I think am supposed to show $$\int_{2}^{4} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{4} \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}} < \infty$$ Does your answer change?

Comment: @BCLC:  Yes -- because the function is decreasing the right Riemann sum and the lower sum are the same.  The answer does not change.  You transformed the integral under a change of variables $u = 2x-4$ which puts the upper limit at $4$.  Changing variables again with $v = u/4$, the integral becomes $\int_0^1v^{-1/2} \, dv$ -- the form I used.

Comment: Also changing variables is only a notational convenience.  You can define an equivalent sequence of step functions on the interval $[2,4]$ and apply MCT.